# Finding primary factors of the number(which is part of the both keys) generated using RSA

Tags: java, rsa

I have public key generated by the RSA (e; n), and the private one (d; n). I have got all this 3 numbers for example:

```
n=113753..47267
e=4978..2634861
d=352...1223909
```

With that knowledge how to find primary factors of n?

Comment: http://jcla1.com/blog/2011/12/10/rsa-public-private-key-encryption-explained/ - moep

Comment: You can't factorise `n` just by using those numbers, but you can encrypt/decrypt using the public/private key. The `p` and `q` you're looking for are already gone ....

Answer (score 1):

You cannot factorize n (that's actually the point on which RSA cryptosystem is based).
Under 'cannot' I mean, as usually in cryptography, 'cannot do that in the reasonable time'.